# Run command line commands from python within Azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a Python function app hosted within Azure. When the user calls on a certain API, I am trying to get a command line command to delete a blob that is stored in an azure storage account.
This is my code within the API:

```
 os.system("az storage blob delete --container-name containername --name name --connection-string connectionStringKey")
```

This does correctly delete the blob when I run the function app locally, but when I deploy it to Azure it does not delete the blob. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any error message?

You can use `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.run` to inspect the output/error message.

Comment: I ended up just using the provided blob service client provided by Microsoft https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_hello_world.py